# Rename all columns of a dataframe removing all characters, if any, before the last slash

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a dataframe where some, but *not* all, columns start with weird prefixes. For example,
`ot1/pr1/cp1/dkjsakhka`, `gt2/pr1/fl1/ct4/rmt12/dasljdals`, etc. I want to rename all columns which have slashes in their names by removing all the characters before the last slash, e.g. `ot1/pr1/cp1/dkjsakhka` -> `dkjsakhka`, `gt2/pr1/fl1/ct4/rmt12/dasljdals` -> `dasljdals`, while leaving the other column names untouched. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[-1]
```

Output:

```
# before
>>> df.columns
Index(['untouched column', 'ot1/pr1/cp1/dkjsakhka',
       'gt2/pr1/fl1/ct4/rmt12/dasljdals'],
      dtype='object')

# after
>>> df.columns
Index(['untouched column', 'dkjsakhka', 'dasljdals'], dtype='object')
```

EDIT:

You can also use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) if you prefer:

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: x.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1], axis=1)
```

Comment: what would be the advantage of using `rename`? I think the first solution is more readable, isn't it (maybe faster too)?

Comment: Some people (like me :)) prefer to chain methods to transform a dataframe but you are right the first method is more readable and faster ;)